# C# WPF SQL Server: How to clear Combo box items

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have 2 comboboxes: in `cbo #1`, items are added manually. When the user selects a value from `cbo# 1`, it should dynamically fill the second combo box items list. But when user selects a different item from `cbo# 1`, the `cbo# 2` item list does not clear up and its list is populated again and again as user select different items from `cbo# 1`. When I add `combobox.Items.Clear()` method, the code breaks down.

First Combo box items are added by "xml code" as given below While 2nd combobox gets its items dynamically from SQL Server table by code.

xaml.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboCat" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="5" Margin="10,2,20,10" Grid.Row="7" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="comboCat_SelectionChanged"> <ComboBoxItem Content="AC"/> <ComboBoxItem Content="Fridge"/> <ComboBoxItem Content="LED TV"/>
```

C#.

```
private void comboCat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)comboCat.SelectedItem;
    comboCategorySelection = cbi.Content.ToString();

    string connection = "Data Source = MCR-CDA-6003\\MSSQLSERVERNEW; Initial Catalog = 99Bell-ERP; Integrated Security = True";

    using (var cc = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {                
        string CmdString = "select ModelNo from Product where CompanyID = 'PEL' and Category = '" + comboCategorySelection + "' group by Category, ModelNo";
        MessageBox.Show(CmdString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Product");
        sda.Fill(dt1);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            comboModel.Items.Add(dr["ModelNo"].ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void comboModel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string connection = "Data Source = MCR-CDA-6003\\MSSQLSERVERNEW; Initial Catalog = 99Bell-ERP; Integrated Security = True";

    using (var cc = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        string CmdString = "select ProductID from Product where ModelNo = '" + comboModel.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(CmdString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Product");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt1);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
        {
            txtProductID.Text = dr["ProductID"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you add the items?

Comment: First Combo box items are added by "xml code"   as given below While 2nd combobox gets its items dynamically from SQL Server table by above code                                                                                       <ComboBox x:Name="comboCat" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="5" Margin="10,2,20,10" Grid.Row="7" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="comboCat_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="AC"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Fridge"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="LED TV"/>

Comment: could you not just do a <cbobox>.Items.Clear() prior to populating it from the selectionchange? Right above your foreach statement try `cboModel.Items.Clear();`

Comment: you should also read up  on the executeScalar() method for returning a single result in a query, a lot less overhead than using an adapter to fill a table. And you shouldn't need a loop to get that single piece of information from the datatable if you just grab it from `dt1.Rows[0].Cells[0]`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Still problem is there and code breakes down

Comment: please modify my above code and send me if it is possible for u.thanks

Comment: code breaks down is very vague. Can you edit and give specific error messages?

Comment: If i do not use cboModel.Items.Clear() in the code then code does not breakes. While using the clear() method code breakes and gives the error "Null ReferenceException was unhandeled"

Comment: Please modify my above code and send me b/c i am new to C#

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cboModel.Items.Clear();`, set it to a new empty collection/list.

`cboModel.Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();` or
`cboModel.Items = new List<string>();`

Comment: please modify my code and send me as i am new in C# and do not know how to use ur above mentioned solution

Comment: You said that when you add "cboModel.Items.Clear();" in your project, the code breaks. Try using one of my methods above just like you did when you did this: "DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Product");"

Could you send me what data type your comboModel is?